# Android:Is is possible to have on the screen 1 layout and a part of the second displayed simultaneously?

Tags: android

I am new in developing apps for android and I need some help.My app needs a layout bigger than the device screen,but not twice (let's say x1.5).I need to fling(using animation) the currently displayed layout on half of its size and the second one to "enter" the screen(again with animation) - the goal is to have half of the main layout always on the screen - it's content (imageViews and Buttons) is common for both layouts.I almost succeed using Flipper,the animation is running ok but the flipper has a restriction - only one child can be displayed on the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have say, a linear layout, containing your static part and flipper.  Then the flipper would contain the two interchangeable layouts.  When you flip between the two, the static part would always stay on the screen.

Comment: Exactly as I indicated.  In your XML, have LinearLayout as the parent, set its orientation to vertical; inside add, for example, ImageView followed by a flipper.  Then add views to your flipper and start flipping them.  The ImageView will remain static at the top.